# I2C: Is DMA required?

Tags: temperature, stm32

I'm trying to port some example code from the [ST standard library](http://www.st.com/internet/com/SOFTWARE_RESOURCES/SW_COMPONENT/FIRMWARE/stm32f2xx_stdperiph_lib.zip) examples. Specifically, there is a file called `stm32_eval_i2c_tsensor.c` that read and write registers for the temperature sensor, and read the temperature.

I do not understand why DMA was used here. The responses from the temperature sensor are at most two bytes long. The most difficult part of the porting is the DMA, and I would much prefer to use "polling" instead.

Is DMA really required here to read the temperature of a temperature sensor?

Comment: How often does that sensor need to be read?

Comment: @Telaclavo: The sensor only needs to be read once an hour. Is it possible to do polling for two consecutive response bytes?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do polling for two consecutive response bytes. To read two bytes per hour (either consecutive or not), you don't need DMA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's quite possible that the reason for using DMA may be found in the [STM32 errata](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/ERRATA_SHEET/CD00197763.pdf) (the link is for the «high density» stm32f101/103 subfamily), a document as fascinating as the reference manual itself. Basically, the I2C peripheral is broken in many interesting ways. One of errata items (2.11.1) states that certain hardware events need to be serviced immediately, or some kind of hardware race condition may occur:

> When the EV7, EV7_1, EV6_1, EV6_3, EV2, EV8, and EV3 events are not
>   managed before the current byte is being transferred, problems may be
>   encountered such as receiving an extra byte, reading the same data
>   twice or missing data.

Basically, the correct operation is not guaranteed in all cases unless I2C is serviced by highest priority interrupts (Workaround 2) or DMA (Workaround 1). Now if I'm reading it correctly, a simple polled transfer with all interrupts disabled would work too, but that's against the whole design philosophy of Cortex-M (concurrency goes out the window). If a preemptive RTOS is used, it's even worse.

That said, multiple people have got I2C working in both polling and interrupt modes without strictly following errata recommendations and without apparent problems. This however cannot be taken as indication that a problem will never occur, of course. If you're going to implement your own I2C driver, I'd recommend that you handle not only all possible error conditions as signaled by the peripheral, but timeouts as well. If an error or a timeout happens, make sure to send a STOP (to reset slaves) and reset the controller itself as documented in the manual. Receiving bad data from slaves is also a possibility that you should think about. You can find many discussions of this problem in ST forums and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say how the sensor is interfaced except mentioning IIC in your title.  If it's IIC, then all it really needs is IIC being implemented over two pins.  DMA is a means inside the processor of dealing with I/O data, which has nothing directly to do with how that peripheral does signalling to the outside world.

In other words, IIC and DMA are independent concepts.  I'm surprised that DMA is even a option for something as slow as IIC, but apparently your processor implements that from what you say.  I am not familiar with that processor, but most likely the IIC peripheral can be run in other I/O modes, like explicitly polling or interrupt driven.

Step back and think about the problem you are trying to solve.  IIC is a simple protocol that can be easily implemented with firmware directly controlling two I/O lines as long as you are the master.  With a processor reading a temperature sensor, the processor will be the master, so this is no problem.

This is a great example of spending more time trying to get someone else's code to work for you than to just do it yourself.  In the small system embedded world you need to understand the low levels anyway.  If you don't understand how IIC works, then stop and learn it before continuing.  That's part of the job.  Just blindly calling someone else's library is going to get you into trouble, and has already wasted more time than (gasp!) writing your own code.

Comment: I agree; DMA is only useful in high bandwidth applications. I do see disadvantages with polling on low-bandwidth applications, because the application will be waiting on the slow commands to execute. But as I2C is very slow it can easily be buffered and performed in a couple of interrupts.

Comment: DMA is a suggested workaround to get I2C to work reliably on STM32. See my answer.